# Input field properties for select field?

Tags: php, html, html-select, html-input

I would like to know if there is a possibility to add some information to a select option field.

I have an input field which will be hidden by a php variable.

```
<input type="<?php echo ($var === '1' ? 'hidden' : 'text'); ?>">
```

Now I'm looking for a solution for a select options field.

I look for a way not to use javascript. I know the javascript solution already but in my case I wont use javascript.

I would really appreciate if there is anybody who could help.

Comment: What type of information are you looking to add? Are you just trying to hide the option in a certain scenario?

Comment: hello, exactly. i would like to hide when $var="1"

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML5, you should use options with "data-" prefix if you need extra info related to DOM. If you mean to post this data then there is no straightforward way.. you either hold it in other fields or use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand completely, are you trying to hide the select based on a PHP variable?

If so, you could do it on the CSS level:

```
<select name="sel" <?php if($var == 1){echo 'style="visibility:hidden"';}?>>
    <option>Opt 1</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: After reading it again, you can do it for each option like this:

```
<select name="sel" >
    <?php 
    if($var == 1)
     {
       echo '<option>Opt 1</option>';
     }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about "hiding" the option, just don't create the option when `$var === '1'`. Like this:

```
<select>
    <?php echo ($var === '1' ? "" : "<option>Option 1</option>"); ?>
</select>
```